# WebStorm complains "SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs » @vue/eslint-config-typescript': ..."

Tags: vue.js, eslint, webstorm, typescript-eslint, pnpm

In WebStorm, every ts file in my project shows the error:

> `SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs » @vue/eslint-config-typescript': Unexpected token '||='`

like this:
[image]

Full stacktrace is:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs » @vue/eslint-config-typescript': Unexpected token '||='
Referenced from: /Users/kio/Projects/ctc/living-environment-web/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmmirror.com+@vue+eslint-config-typescript@12.0.0_eslint-plugin-vue@9.17.0_eslint@8.51.0_typescript@5.2.2/node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-typescript/index.js

/Users/kio/Projects/ctc/living-environment-web/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmmirror.com+@typescript-eslint+scope-manager@6.7.5/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/dist/referencer/ClassVisitor.js:123
        withMethodDecorators ||=
                             ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kio/Projects/ctc/living-environment-web/node_modules/.pnpm/registry.npmmirror.com+@typescript-eslint+scope-manager@6.7.5/node_modules/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/dist/referencer/Referencer.js:20:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

---

`.eslintc.cjs` file

```js
/* eslint-env node */
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution')

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier/skip-formatting'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  },
  rules: {
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0
  }
}
```

`package.json` file:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@amap/amap-jsapi-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "@element-plus/icons-vue": "^2.1.0",
    "@szxc/apis": "workspace:^",
    "@szxc/components": "workspace:^",
    "@szxc/http": "workspace:^",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.8",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "element-plus": "^2.3.14",
    "gcoord": "^1.0.5",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pinia": "^2.1.6",
    "pinia-plugin-persist": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-plugin-px2rem": "^0.8.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "sass": "^1.69.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.0.6",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "~5.2.0",
    "unplugin-auto-import": "^0.16.6",
    "unplugin-vue-components": "^0.25.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.11"
  }
```

I added two dependencies:

```json
{
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.0"
}
```

and didn't fix the error.

---

Then I upgraded the eslint-plugin-vue to "^9.18.0"

```json
{
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
}
```

useless as well.

Answer (score 0):

What Node.js interpreter version do you have selected in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js**? Looks like it doesn't support logical OR assignment (`||=`) operator. Node.js 15 or greater is required,please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#browser_compatibility